# I cant able to send email using django even I gave all permission from google side

Tags: python, django, django-email

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIT_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL= False


 send_mail(msg,"Thank-You for using our Website ,Mail us if you have any Problem in Our Website.Thank-You Once again" ,
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[emailto,],fail_silently=False,)
```

I cant send mail it showing `timeout error` even i have tried

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

I cant send the mail instead of that i am getting printed in console box

```
[11/Sep/2020 23:07:49] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3502
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Hello User
From: tamilan0tamill@gmail.com
To: bahubali@gmail.com
Date: Fri, 11 Sep 2020 17:39:50 -0000
Message-ID: <159984599099.7876.4877994479538514933@UNIVERSE>

Thank-You for using our Website ,Mail us if you have any Problem in Our Website.
```

Comment: I suppose you did not intentionally write `EMAIT_PORT`?

Comment: What is `send_mail`?

Comment: By far the most people having troubles sending mail on SO are using Gmail. You might want to try any other provider.

Comment: Console backend is for testing purposes you need SMTP backend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#smtp-backend
@mkrieger1 Django specific mail sending function https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#send-mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have removed this line in your settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Making sure the `EMAIL_BACKEND` is set to:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

You will also have to go to your Google Account settings and enable `Access for less secure apps`.
You can find steps on this here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=637354451790607458-1295615873&rd=2#cantsignin